# Modify parent from child in javafx 17.0.2

Tags: java, javafx, parent

When I try modifying a parent (borderpane) from a child (button), I get a nullpointerexception on the borderpane. On the other hand, if the button is outside the borderpane, it works.

Everything that is in the borderpane is loaded from other FXMLs.

I tried using a single controller or multiple ones but nothing changes.
I tried creating a single Loader function so that is independent:

```java
public void loader(String page) throws IOException {
        content.setCenter(null);
        content.setCenter(FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(MainApplication.class.getResource(page))));
    }
```

Comment: The only place you can access the border pane is in the actual controller that was created when you loaded the FXML that specifies that border pane. So you need to call a method (or otherwise arrange for a method to be called) on that specific controller instance.